# Editing an entity is saved without my approval with NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I've got this test code:

```
int productId;
{
    var codersAtWork = productService.Create();
    codersAtWork.Title = "Coders At Work";
    codersAtWork.Price = new Price(200, 160, 0.25m, "SEK");

    codersAtWork.FieldBag.ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2009, 9, 1);
    productService.Save(codersAtWork);
    productId = codersAtWork.Id;
}

ReSetUp(); // Closes and opens a new session

{
    var codersAtWork = productService.GetById(productId);
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2009, 9, 1), codersAtWork.FieldBag.ReleaseDate);

    codersAtWork.FieldBag.ReleaseDate = "Tomorrow";
    Assert.Throws<InvalidFieldException>(() => { productService.Save(codersAtWork); });

    var cleanCode = productService.Create();
    cleanCode.Title = "Foo";
    cleanCode.Price = new Price(300, 240, 0.25m, "SEK");
    cleanCode.FieldBag.ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2009, 9, 1);
    productService.Save(cleanCode); // This save will also save my incorrect product.
}

ReSetUp(); // Closes and opens a new session

{
    var codersAtWork = productService.GetById(productId);
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2009, 9, 1), codersAtWork.FieldBag.ReleaseDate);
}
```

I want my service to validate the product I send to it and only save it if it's valid. But the problem is that when I save something else that is valid in the same session or call Flush on the session, it will be save without me having any control of it being valid. The last assert here will fail. product.FieldBag.ReleaseDate will be "Tomorrow".

FieldBag is dynamic and is saved as Json to the database. But the problem is valid for other validation also.

Can NHibernate be configured to only save items I explicitly called .SaveOrUpdate() on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use event handlers to do this. You can use PreInsertEventListener and the PreUpdateEventListener. Check for your validation and return true if validation fails to veto the action.

http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events

Answer (score 4):

You can call `Session.Evict()` to remove entities from the session. Then NHibernate will ignore changes to these entities.

Alternatively you can get/query them with a `StatelessSession`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can evict the object using `Session.Evict()` I would suggest taking a look at your approach for validation.  If I am understanding you correctly then your `productService.Save` method is doing the checks that the passed in object is valid.  Instead of checking that an object is valid with some type of service manager you should move that validation into the object itself and have the object ensure it never becomes invalid.

For Example:

```
class House
{
    public Room Bedroom { get; set; }
}

class HouseService
{
    public ValidateHouse(House aHouse)  //There is no guarantee that this method is ever called
    {
        if (aHouse.Bedroom == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidFieldException();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example you can not guarantee that ValidateHouse is ever called and therefor can not guarantee that you have a valid house to save (or do anything with).

Move validation into the object:

```
class House
{
    private Room theBedroom;
    public Room Bedroom 
    { 
        get
        {
            return theBedroom;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
            theBedroom = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example it is guaranteed that Bedroom will never be null.  If someone tries to assign null to the Bedroom then the exception is thrown and the object is never changed.  Since the object isn't changed NHibernate won't try and persist it.  In addition this should benefit your entire application since you'll know your objects will always be in a valid state.

```
house.Bedroom = null;
house.Bedroom.ToString(); //With option 1 this will throw a NullPointerException.

house.Bedroom = null;  //With option 2 this will throw an ArgumentNullException 
                       //but your house object will still be in a known valid state.
house.Bedroom.ToString();
```